How to prove that a linear function such that $f(AB) = f(A)f(B)$ doesn't exist?
I am asked to show that there does not exist a function $f:M_n \to \mathbb{R}$ that has the same defining properties as the determinant, except with multilinearity replaced by linearity:
$$
f(I)=1
$$
$$
f(AB)=f(A)f(B)
$$
$$
f(A+cB)= f(A)+cf(B).
$$
Those for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $A,B \in M_n$.
I've read one way of solving an analogous problem, but I would like to let this post open to all possible forms of proof just to embrace different approaches for those who are new to this kind of problem (like me).

The function mapping everything to $0$ answers your title question but doesn't satisfy $f(I)=1$

If $n=1$, $f$ can be the identity transformation.

Note that $e_{11}e_{22} = 0$, so $0 = f(e_{11}e_{22}) = f(e_{11})f(e_{22})$. Hence, one of $f(e_{11})$ and $f(e_{22})$ must be $0$. WLOG, we may assume $f(e_{11}) = 0$. Thus, for any $1 \leq i, j \leq n$, we have,
$$f(e_{ij}) = f(e_{i1}e_{11}e_{1j}) = f(e_{i1})f(e_{11})f(e_{1j}) = 0$$
Since $e_{ij}$ spans $M_n$, by linearity, we have $f = 0$. This shows that any $f$ that is both multiplicative and linear must be the zero functional. In particular, it cannot satisfy $f(I) = 1$.

Of course this assumes $n \ge 2$.

@RobertIsrael Yes, of course.
